# How to make a wearos app exit the activity after a button press?

Tags: android, wear-os

the documentation says don't worry about it, the user will swipe left to right.

But the stopwatch app included on my ticwatch e has an "X" button that exits the stopwatch app.

That's what I want to do, but I don't see any API way of doing that.
For reasons I can't yet explain, my test app does almost nothing, but when it's running it sucks up the battery like crazy, so I just want it to exit the activity, that's the only thing running, I have to assume it's related to that.

Is there some known way of programmtically exiting the activity?

Answer (score 0):

never mind I found it.
there's the finish() function.
does exactly that.